# Prolog code not workin on SWISH

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

The dog can perform the
following actions: walk on floor; climb the box (if it is already at the box); and grasp the meat if standing on the box directly under the meat. but when i run the code below but i get an Error

> procedure `(A:-B)' does not exist Reachable from:
>   swish_trace:swish_call((start:-canget(state(atdoor,onfloor,atwindow,hasmeat))))
>       '$swish
>   wrapper'((start:-canget(state(atdoor,onfloor,atwindow,hasmeat))),A)

```
    move(state(middle,onbox,middle,has_no_meat),state(middle,onbox,middle,has_meat)).
/*climbing the box*/

 move(state(middle_floor, onfloor, middle_floor,has_no_meat), climb,

  state(middle_floor,onbox, middle_floor,has_meat)).

 /*pushing the box to the middle of the room*/

 move(state(atwindow,onfloor,atwindow,has_box),      
 push(atwindow,middle_floor),

 state(middle_floor,onfloor,middle_floor,has_box)).

 /*dog walks from the door to the window*/

   move(state(atdoor,onfloor,box,has_not), walk(atdoor,atwindow),

   state(atwindow,onfloor,box,has_box)).

   canget(state(_, _, _, has_meat)).

   canget(State1) :- move(State1, Move, State2), canget(State2).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't undertand exactly what do you want to do but...

1) according the error message, if I understand correctly, you're trying to validate the goal

```
canget(state(atdoor,onfloor,atwindow,hasmeat))
```

so using `hasmeat` instead of `has_meat`

2) using `has_meat`, the goal is immediatly true thanks to the fact

```
canget(state(_, _, _, has_meat))
```

so I suppose that your starting fact should be something with `has_no_meat`

3) You're first `move` is a `move/2` (a couple of states) instead `move/3` (state, action, state); I suggest to add an action; something like

```
move(state(middle,onbox,middle,has_no_meat),
     take_meat,
     state(middle,onbox,middle,has_meat)).
```

4) In the following `canget` rule

```
 canget(State1) :- move(State1, Move, State2), canget(State2).
```

`Move` is a singleton variable; if you dont use it (`write(Move)`?) it's only a source of disturbing warnings; I suggest to rewrite it as

```
canget(State1) :-
   move(State1, _, State2),
   canget(State2).
```